# How can I mention a user who sent a message using Chat Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Sorry, English is not my native language, and I'm new to JS.
I'm making my bot discord, I need it to send random messages in the chat in a period of time, this part I've got the code below.
however I also need the bot to mention the last user to have sent a message in the chat
and I have no idea how to add this to my code

```
async function notifLoop(){
  while(true){
    client.channels.cache.get('764266751734054953').send("test text");
    await Sleep(10000)
  }
}

function Sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

client.on('ready', function(){
    notifLoop();
    console.log("Ready");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need it to send random messages in the chat in a period of time

[So](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572364/random-response-to-message-discord-js) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894234/how-can-i-make-a-random-response-in-discord-js) [people](https://github.community/t/need-discord-bot-to-respond-with-random-messages-upon-command/116309) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584617/discord-js-bot-command-that-says-a-sentence-from-a-random-list-of-premade-ones) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097858/random-message-reply-discord-js-2020) [asked](https://support.glitch.com/t/need-help-with-discordjs-bot/18616) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937374/get-random-item-from-javascript-array-repeatedly) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622251/discord-js-trying-to-create-a-random-outcome-command-with-2-arrays); [please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211863/pick-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array) [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array) [research](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-array-exercise-35.php) [before](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-select-a-random-element-from-array-in-javascript/) [asking](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/picking_random_item_from_array.htm)

---

> I also need the bot to mention the last user to have sent a message in the chat

You can use a combination of [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) and [`Collection.prototype.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first). First, you have to use `MessageManager.fetch()` to fetch the last message in the channel. This function returns a collection of messages, of which you only need the first of (as you are getting the first message in the channel).

You can find a list of ways to mention a user from the User/GuildMember object in the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64433639/how-to-make-a-discord-js-bot-say-custom-messages-in-a-specific-channel-tag-a-u/64434599#64434599)

```js
async function notifLoop() {
 const channel = client.channels.cache.get('764266751734054953');
 while (true) {
  const user = channel.messages
   .fetch({ limit: 1 })
   .then((msg) => channel.send(`The user was <@${msg.author.id}>`));
  await Sleep(10000);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this to mention the user :

```
  message.reply(`${message.author}`);
```

> and you can use this too :

```
  message.reply(`<@${message.author.id}>`);
```

Comment: `message.reply(\`${message.author}\`)` would actually return `@E3saR, @E3saR`